# Manga or manhwa where the female lead regresses and tries to win the love of the duke multiple times

Tags: story-identification, manga, webcomics

There's a girl who is Duke's wife but the Duke is in love with her sister but still married the MC because of political reasons. In her first life when she hears that her sister died, she smirks and when the Duke comes home, he pins the blame that the MC was the reason her sister died and she is sentenced to prison. Then she is reborn after dying in the prison on the same day when Duke and her sister meet for some tea for the first time. This repeats several times where she tries to win the love of the Duke back but fails.

In some of her rebirths, she meets a creature which first appears to her as a crow but can change into other things too. She waits for him in her every life but he shows himself only in some of them.

As that hell continues to happen, one day she notices the Duke is doing something different from her previous lives but as it turns out, Duke also started to have conflicting but his body would move the same way as always even if he didn't want to.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Was it in colour?

Comment: Do you recall the hair colour of the female lead and/or the male lead?

Comment: @DavidW yeah I found my answer. It's called! My finance is in in love with my little sister?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you maybe looking for [My Fiance is in Love with My little Sister](https://vyvymanga.net/manga/my-fianc-is-in-love-with-my-little-sister) ...?

> There my fiancé stood, gazing intently at my charming younger sister. When I saw them fall in love the moment they laid eyes on each other, I was hit with an overwhelming sense of déjà vu. Aah, again? My fiancé had been in love with my younger sister even in my previous life. There was nothing I could do but watch it all unfold. And for some inexplicable reason, I'm the only one who keeps returning to that exact point in time. Trapped by fate. And yet, amidst the turns of the hourglass, I still find myself falling for him…

The first scene you mention where she smirks after hearing of the death of her sister in her first life can be found in chapter 3:

[image: chapter3 MC smirks at little sisters death]

The first appearance of the crow is in chapter 5

[image: first appearance of the crow]

As of now the manga has 21 released chapters. I'm unsure of the current state of the manga, but I know that the original webnovel is nearly finished. Although the last chapters were only released sporadically, so even the state of the webnovel is kinde up in the air.